# Create a bar to decrease or increase a variable pygame

Tags: python, pygame

[image]
As you can see in the picture I inserted (from a game called Victoria 2), I want to create a bar in pygame to modify a variable (the number of pounds below the bar) depending on which part of the bar the gamer clicks (if they click on the left part of the bar, the red circle moves there and decrease the variable and if click on the right part, the circle moves there and increase the variable).
I tried:

```
        if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if mouse_rect.colliderect(bar_rect) and event.button==1:
                circle_rect.x=mouse_rect.x
                if circle_rect.x+mouse_rect.x:
                    budget=budget+1
                if circle_rect.x-mouse_rect.x:
                    budget=budget-1
```

The circle moves, but the variable `budget` increases always, no matter if clicked on left or right, and it only increases one by one (because  I don't know any other way  to do it and what I want is a bigger or smaller increase depending on how far you click from the circle).
Any help?
Thanks!!!

Victoria 2 is a strategy game which allows you to balance the budget of your Goverment through a bar. Depending on where you clicked of the bar (left or right), the budget increases or decreases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at how far along the slider you've clicked. Here's some untested code to show what I mean:

```
if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if mouse_rect.colliderect(bar_rect) and event.button==1:
        # move circle to clicked point
        circle_rect.centerx=mouse_rect.x
        # calculate distance from the slider origin
        delta = circle_rect.centerx - bar_rect.left
        # determine the percentage of the total budget
        budget_pct = delta // (circle_rect.width)
        # recalculate budget
        budget = budget_pct * budget_max
```